# Incorrectly displayed characters in vim quick fix window

Tags: vim

While compiling code using vim (not gvim) the output looks fine in the terminal window but when vim returns and displays the text in the quick fix window it has some incorrectly displayed characters.  All other times in my terminal and in vim everything is displayed correctly.  Any ideas?

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the version of vim I was using didn't have +multi_byte compiled in.  Once adding that the problem went away.