# Vim show strange Â characters over putty

Tags: vim, encoding, character, putty

When I am editing a file in Vim I have some lines with a bunch
of Â displayed.

I have already checked the encoding with

```
:set encoding
```

It says utf8

```
encoding=utf8
```

Anybody knows where this is comming from and how to stop 
this behaviour?

Regards,

Jeremy

Comment: You might have the same problem I did check out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580154/incorrectly-displayed-characters-in-vim-quick-fix-window

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Make sure that PuTTY is set for UTF-8 as well. You can do this under Window -> Translation -> Remote Character Set. You may need to choose a font that supports a reasonable portion of the Unicode range as well -- Terminal isn't necessarily going to cut it.

Comment: Thank you, Hobbs! Your advice worked for me using SecureCRT, too!  The visual mode of Aptitude was showing all kinds of odd characters.  I changed the Character Set from "default" to UTF-8, and everything looked great!  Thank you!! :-)

Comment: Didn't realize those symbols showed up because the character didn't exist in Courier New. It's just unfortunate, because I don't like the other console fonts

Comment: It worked for me setting UTF-8 in translation and using Consolas as font. I've tested pretty much all the fonts that where available in my putty installation and it was the only one showing arroww.

Answer (score 5):

Does it appear when you type the British Pound symbol? Try changing your encoding:

```
:set encoding=latin1
```

Comment: Wow, you really helped me to find those hidden chars on this problem I just had. Thanks! :)