# Bash script produces bullets in filename

Tags: linux, bash

I new to bash scripts. By doing "Google search programming," I've managed to write this one:

```
#------------------------
_dir="/volume1/Shared/sqlbackup/"
_date=`date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S"`
_file="$_dir$_date.gz"
/usr/syno/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u username -ppassword database | gzip > "$_file"
#------------------------
```

At the end of running it using a Windows 7 telnet interface, I get a filename that looks something like this, when viewing it on a Windows 7 share:

```
2013_10_09_13_38_36.gz
```

The "?" boxes here show up as bullets (like •) on Windows. Obviously, I'm doing something wrong. Does anyone have suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any difference in the output if you use `cat -v script.sh`?

Comment: It works for me with no strange characters. /volume1/Shared/sqlbackup/2013_10_09_15_35_57.gz

Comment: telnet??? means you are connecting to a linux box using telnet? you may have then an encoding issue as Linux could use UTF8 for output but your w7 telnet could use cp1252 or some other ms codepage.

Comment: Luis: Your suggestion makes sense, but I have no other way to run commands against this box, a Synology NAS. Also, using PuTTY, I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: look at first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027403/vim-show-strange-characters-over-putty it may help you. This may also help to enable ssh on the NAS: http://www.gizmojunkee.com/2013/09/howto-synology-ds-network-attached-storage-nas-enable-ssh-or-telnet/

Comment: how about adding some debugging lines , like echo "X${_dir}X,Y${_date}Y" , also change the line to : /usr/syno/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u username -ppassword database | gzip > $_file

Comment: Adding the echo lines as shown outputs some odd stuff: }Y, Y{2013_10_09_14_38_57/sqlbackup/

Comment: Your script has DOS line endings (CR+LF), while `bash` expects UNIX line endings (LF only). The CRs are being included in the variable assignments.

Comment: Yes, thank you chepner. I brushed up on VI and edited out the ^M endings that appeared there. However, I thought I had already considered this possibility by using Notepad++ and selecting the Unix SH file type when saving. Apparently, this wasn't enough to fix the problem. However, it is now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dos2unix and unix2dos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) utilities to convert text files between Linux and Windows formatting. e.g.

```
dos2unix script.sh
```

Comment: Those convert from linefeed to crlf and vice versa, they have nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: @koodawg - If I read chepner's comment (upvoted) and Brent's reply it sounds as if this is exactly the problem.  Running dos2unix on the script before the script was run would have been a simple fix to this problem.